# Unity2D Input.touches management for drag 2 lines simultaneously

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, touch

I'm doing a shotting arrow game multiplayer in android device in which you shoot depending of the line you draw. But i need 2 lines in the same screen and i don't know what is the right way to implements that.
The PROBLEM is that the Touches array is static and common for the 2 instances, therefore the Index array changes and the value of the touch that i wanna control changes too.

I tried to do 1 script for 2 GameObject with 1 line renderer

```
  for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
            {
                if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                {
                    if (touchIndex == -1)
                        touchIndex = Input.GetTouch(i).fingerId;

                    startPointLine = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(touchIndex).position);

                }
//this if for the RIGHT half screen management
                if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Moved && (TouchHalfRightScreen && IsRightDraggingZone))
                {

                    endPointLine = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(touchIndex).position); 
                    Dragging();
                }
//this if for the LEFT half screen management
                if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Moved && (!TouchHalfRightScreen && !IsRightDraggingZone))
                {
                    if (Input.touchCount == 1 && touchIndex == 1)
                        touchIndex--;
                    endPointLine = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(touchIndex).position); 
                    Dragging();
                }
                if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                {
                    //reset touchIndex
                    touchIndex = -1;
                    ClearLine();
                }
            }
```

I expect the touch i save in indexTouch is that i manage, but in the game i do a drag line in one of both sides of the screen, then i add a dragline in the otherside and what happens? The first line i drawd is freezeed, but the last is moving.

To clarify a bit, this is the drag line that i want draw simultaneously.
https://img2.androidappsapk.co/poster/9/d/7/com.stickmanarcher.stickmanfightinggames.archerygames.stickman_5.png

[image]

Comment: Can you add a gif or video?

Comment: Of course, https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YP8vQ6S13_NNN_OK1yfpkTL2yybUzcZ-